# "Non-Intentional Lifeform" logo font identification

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I'm trying to identify a font used by a short lived Australian metal band back in the '90s for their logo, as below. They had a 1996 EP and 1997 LP on Roadrunner before disbanding - both used the same logo. A post break-up single used a similar typeface, but also abbreviated the band name to "n.i.l." which isn't hugely helpful. Album artwork is credited to the band and "Black Widow Graphic Design" who still exist (and might get an email from me if nobody is able to ID the font here.)

[image: Non-Intentional Lifeform]

There's a non-zero chance that it never actually existed as a font, or that it is lost to time, but I thought I'd ask after having no luck using the various font identification tools in the [Font ID requirements post](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366).

Even though it is super tropey (Katakana-ish Romaji), the lack of kerning, inconsistent serifs, lack of upper-case letters, and stylised design mean that visual algorithms struggle, and "How long is the serif on the uppercase G?" style questionnaires end up with a lot of "not sure" responses.

I've also tried various keywords ("japanese", "katakana", "korean", "hangul", "chinese") and there are plenty of other fonts trying to meet the same brief, but nothing quite as distinctive. The closest I could get is [Morioka by Mhdafifersya](https://www.fontspace.com/morioka-free-font-f89354) on Fontspace.

Any ideas?